# Is it possible to upscale a windowed game?

Tags: windows-7, directx-11

I'm using Win7 and will upgrade to Win10 next year.

I bought a GTX 1070 to run games in 4K. Some run smooth @ 60FPS, others are barely able to sustain 30FPS.

Even though I wanna play games @ 4K, I'd rather go lower resolution to keep 60FPS. But of course I don't wanna play on a small window, I'd need some way to resize the game's window to fullscreen.

Is there any way to do it transparently to games? In example, set them to windowed mode @ 1080p and upscale the window to 4K?

Edit: Unfortinately playing games on fullscreen isn't an option. I really need to play them on windowed mode.

The best solution would also include making the window borderless, many games have that available but only on a "maximized borderless window", if it's not maximized its window gets a border. Some games make it even worse, forcing fullscreen when its window is maximized.

Answer (score 6):

## Fullscreenizer solution

One possible solution is to download [**Fullscreenizer**](http://runtimeterror.com/tools/fullscreenizer/) [(direct download)](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?6utvc3azpe0ugy5), which is a free, portable, and open source tool for Windows. Using it, you can "Fullscreenize" a game (or any application), which forces it into a borderless window, stretched to fill your entire display.

*It also has some other features which make it a better solution than native borderless windowed modes, such as preventing taskbar flickering and preventing popup notifications (optional).*

### How to use Fullscreenizer

You should set the render resolution to windowed 1080p (or your desired downscaled resolution) in your game and then "Fullscreenize" it once you've locked in your settings.

*If you don't see your game or app on the list of programs, click "Refesh" in Fullscreenizer to refresh the list of running programs.*

### Why Fullscreenizer?

Games are inconsistent with how they handle fullscreen and borderless on lower resolutions, so that's why for this case we should rely on an OS-based solution and not a per-game solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about it. I'm gonna install and evaluate it.

Comment: This is incredible! Revolutionary! I tried it with FCPrimal, in Mid settings I was playing @ 40fps 4K. I lowered it to 1080p and with Fillscreenizer I was able to maximize it with a single button click!! Immediately I noticed the graph quality loss (yes, I did, it was very very noticiable!), but disabled vsync and it ran @ 100fps! I upped to Ultra settings and can play above 60fps full time! I ope it works for all games as it worked in FCPrimal, this is exactly what I always needed!

Comment: Glad to help. :>

Comment: link moved: http://runtimeterror.com/tools/fullscreenizer/

Answer (score 2):

Another upScaler is the [IntegerScaler](https://tanalin.com/en/projects/integer-scaler/).

Download, start application, focus desired window to be upscaled, press Alt F11, the window app/game transform into a FullScreen application.

Only drawback, it can only upscale in integer steps.
So window to be upscaled must be half or quarter of full screen size, windows with different proportion will lead to black blocks on sides.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to set it to windowed mode? every game supports 1080p nowdays.
You just need to change the settings in the game.

Or you can actually change the windows 7/10 resolution every time you want to play a game that for some reason doesn't let you set the 1080p resolution. Its quick

Got the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/14108/windows-7-change-screen-resolution

> Open Screen Resolution by clicking the Start button The Start button, clicking Control Panel, and then, under Appearance and Personalization, clicking Adjust screen resolution.
>
> Click the drop-down list next to Resolution, move the slider to the resolution you want, and then click Apply.
>
> Click Keep to use the new resolution, or click Revert to go back to the previous resolution.

you probably can just right click the descktop and select "Display settings" thats how i do it in win10.

Comment: I guess I'm getting old.  "Upscaling" a game used to mean rendering it at a lower resolution that your hardware could manage, and then using a bilinear filter or other fast algorithm to enlarge it to your screen's native resolution.

Comment: you are right, I got confused with Super Sampling Anti-Aliasing

Comment: We wanna play games on windowed mode because we use multi-monitor setups. Games running on fullscreen makes Windows DWM hang every time we minimize and again when we maximize the game. In windowed mode we can instantly Alt-Tab to do other stuff on PC and come back without having whole Windows go nuts. Changing resolution isn't also an option, because it brings havock to windows positions.